# puzzling segmentation problem in C

Tags: c

The declaration of array is bulbState[101]. So it is an array of 101 elements. This is the portion of the code that gives this error.
Before the for loop the hundredth element of the array is printed and after the for loop "After this" String doesn't get printed.

```
void printBulbState()
{
    int i;
    printf("100th %d", bulbState[100]);
    for ( i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
            printf("\nbulbState[%d] = %d", i, bulbState[i]);
    }
    printf("After for");
}
```

Comment: That's ... unusual. Are you certain that the "After for" isn't printing on the same line as item 100? What happens if you change that to `printf("\nAfter for\n");`?

Comment: yes sir "After for" is not printing

Comment: Sure that it is not printed? Add a \n

Comment: How is `bulbState` declared?

Comment: Having the whole code would make things easier. Maybe after `printBulbState` returns you get a segfault and the pending output in buffer is not printed? The code as it is has no reason not to work, if `bulbState` is an array of `int`, and has at least 101 elements.

Comment: You should get into the habit of printing newlines **at the end of a string**. Printing them first seems like a Windows disease. Use `printf ("100th %d\n", bulbState[100]);` etc. In C Standard I/O, if a stream is line-buffered, it gets flushed when a newline is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I added a main() to drive the printBulbState() function and a declaration and initialization of the bulbState array.

I modified the last call to printf()

The root of the problem, I think, is the buffering of the stdout by the OS.
A trailing '\n' in a format string or a call to fflush(stdout) 
causes the buffer to be flushed

Here is the code, which works perfectly

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBulbState( void );

int bulbState[101];

int main( void )
{
    for(int i = 0; i< 101; i++ ) bulbState[i] = i;
    printBulbState();
    return 0;
}


void printBulbState()
{
    int i;
    printf("100th %d", bulbState[100]);
    for ( i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
            printf("\nbulbState[%d] = %d", i, bulbState[i]);
    }
    printf("\nAfter for\n"); // notice format string change
}
```